# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\includes\database\sqlsrv\database.inc on line 64

Tags: drupal, sqlsrv

I have sql server 2014 running on my local machine.  The settings file has the correct db configuration.
Can Anybody tell me how to debug this issue?

Comment: enabling php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the extension in `php.ini` for `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` and `php_sqlsrv.dll` have the same name in